# Put a 1D array into a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array `x` in which I want to copy the content of a 1D array `y` :

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5], [3, 3]], np.int32)
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

x[:,:] = y   # i would like x to be [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6) into shape (3,2)

How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the `y` to an array with a shape like `x`:

```
>>> x = y.reshape(x.shape)
>>> x
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

But note that the `y` should be reshape with `x`'s shape.

Comment: I would have used `x[...] = y.reshape(x.shape)` to stay closer to the original intent.  `x.flat = y` also works.

Comment: @hpaulj Since OP only wanted to change the `x`, I didn't see any reason to assign the `y` to it's view. Or does your recipe has any advantage here that I'm not aware of?